# Why do I need to use a synchronous delay to properly load the posts in rxjs?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using rxjs and have to use a synchronous delay (this.sleep(1000)) or the posts load mixed up. There are racing conditions. How do I fix this?

The solution works correctly and loads the posts through infinite scrolling, but the solution with the delay is a hack. How do I program the code properly without the hack?

### component

```
​
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    ​
    import {  ElementRef, Renderer2  } from '@angular/core';
    ​
    import { Blog } from './blog';
    ​
    import { BlogsService } from './blogs.service';
    ​
    import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
    ​
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-blogs',
      templateUrl: './blogs.component.html',
      /**styleUrls: ['./blogs.component.sass']**/
    })
    export class BlogsComponent  implements OnInit  {
        ​
      blogs: Blog[] = [];
    ​
      page= 0;
    ​
      items : any[] = [];
    ​
      htmlToAdd:string = "";
      constructor(private blogsService: BlogsService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private elementRef:ElementRef ) {}
    ​
      ngOnInit() {    ​
       
    ​
        this.addMoreItems();  
        
      }
    ​
      getBlogs(page:any):void {
        this.blogsService.getBlogs(page)
        .subscribe(blogs =>  
          this.blogs = blogs 
          );
     }
     
     loadData(event: any) {  
     
      let el: HTMLElement = <HTMLElement>event.target;
      let item_height = document.getElementById("my-height")!.clientHeight;
      let distance = el.scrollHeight - (el.scrollTop + el.clientHeight)
      if ((el.scrollTop + el.clientHeight >= el.scrollHeight - 5)) {    ​
       
        this.page += 1;
        
        this.sleep(1000);     
      
      setTimeout(() => {  
        console.log('Done');        ​
     
        this.items.push(...[this.blogs]);   
        this.addMoreItems();         
        
        event.target.complete();  
          
      }, 500);  
     
    }
    }  
    addMoreItems() {  
      
      this.route.queryParams
      .subscribe(params => {
        console.log(params);  
     
      }
    );
    ​​
    (async () => {
    ​
    ​
      try {
        let response = await this.blogsService.getApp(this.page);
    ​
​
        let regex: any = JSON.stringify(response);
    ​
         regex = JSON.parse(regex);
    ​
    ​
         this.items.push(...[regex]);
    ​
​
         console.log(JSON.stringify(this.items));
    ​
        let content = "";
    ​
        for(var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
        
    ​
          for(var y = 0; y < this.items[i].length; y++) {
    ​
          let obj = this.items[i][y];
    ​
          if(!obj) console.log(`obj is undefined at ${i}`, this.items[i]);  
    ​
          console.log('post' + obj.field_title);
 
       content += '<p><strong>' + obj.field_title + '</strong></p><p>' + obj.body + '</p><br/>';
     
    
          }
    ​
    ​
           if(response !== "") {
          this.htmlToAdd = content;
          document.getElementById("my-height")!.scrollTop -= 20;
    ​
           }
             
    }
    ​
   ​
      } catch (error) {
        // error details
        console.error(error);
      }
    })();
    ​
      
    }
       
    sleep(ms: any) {
      var start = new Date().getTime(), expire = start + ms;
      while (new Date().getTime() < expire) { }
      return;
    }
    ​
    }
```

### service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
​
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Blog } from './blog';
​
​
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
​
export class BlogsService {
​
myPage = 0;
 cancel = false;
​
    private blogUrl = 'http://thedietician.net/the-dietician/api/blogs?_format=json';  // update with your drupal path
​
    constructor ( private http: HttpClient) {}
​
    getBlogs(page: any): Observable<Blog[]> {
        
   
       let temp = this.http.get<Blog[]>(this.blogUrl + '&page=' + page);
      
​
        return temp;
    }
​
    async getApp(page: any): Promise<string> {
​
       
     if(this.cancel === true) { return "";}
     else {
        let value: any = await this.http.get(this.blogUrl+ '&page=' + this.myPage).toPromise();
    
        if(JSON.stringify(value) === "[]") { this.cancel = true;} ;
    
        this.myPage++;
    
        return value;
     }
      }
​
}
```

Comment: I feel like I'm infinitely scrolling to see all the code in your question :-)  It would make it easier for others to read if you removed some of the unnecessary empty lines and used separate code blocks for different files.

Comment: I would recommend learning some Angular first and then have another chop, this is pretty terrible. Learn some RxJs, don't use promises and awaits. Don't construct html strings, use template binding.

Comment: As those above have said, you don't need async and await to get data via RxJS. Note, however, that http is asynchronous, so you can't call http get and assume that you have the data right away. When the data is returned, it will execute the callback code in your subscribe. Here is a video that may help with your RxJS code: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtCDRiG__D4